# CMake: add_custom_command with output in build config related directory

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

I've a custom command with some output file.

However there is some issue I have under VisualStudio: the location of generated file is the same for Release and Debug which is not what I want.

I'd like to be able to generate this file in subdir "Relase" or "Debug" as CMake does for all binary files when run with VisualStudio generator.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the CMake variable `CMAKE_CFG_INTDIR` in your custom command, as demonstrated in the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CFG_INTDIR.html).